# For loop not counting correctly, counting from wrong variable somehow?

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

Okay so, I'm making a program for my programming class and I am trying to get it so when I type the column and row, it will get an output showing a multiplication table. Here is an example for you to visualize it: Sample run output for printTable(4,6):

[image: Example:]

Now, here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Pictures {

public static int row;
public static int column;
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){
int x = 1;
int y = 1;

System.out.println("Input Row: ");
row = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input Column: ");
column = input.nextInt();

for(x = 1; x < row; x++){
    System.out.print(x * y +  "    ");

    for(y = 1 ; y < column; y++){

        System.out.print(y * x + "    ");
    }
    System.out.println();   
}   
}
}
```

Now, when I input the row 5, and column 5, my output looks like this:

```
1    1    2    3    4    
10    2    4    6    8    
15    3    6    9    12    
20    4    8    12    16
```

I know I am not seeing something rather simple, but I just don't understand why this is happening. If anyone could offer a suggestion, it would help a lot.

Thanks,
Sully

Comment: You should step through your code in the debugger, and inspect the values of all your variables as you go.

Comment: Why do you print x*y outside second loop?

Comment: Hot licks, I'm sorry that I offended you with my question. Please consider that I am a 10th grade novice with programming.

Comment: If you followed the best practice of declaring variables only when they're needed, and initialize them at the same time, you wouldn't have this bug.

Comment: @JBNizet I did originally initialize the variables inside the for loop, like: "for (int x = 0.........)" but I figured i'd try some new ways of going about this

Comment: Now you know why it's "best practice" to not do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For learning purposes, use a debugger to understand your code.

To fix it, delete those lines:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
```

and have your loops like:

```
for(int x = 1; x < row; x++){
    // System.out.print(x * y +  "    "); // no print needed here
    for(int y = 1 ; y < column; y++){
        System.out.print(y * x + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Here is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to the section of the Oracle Java tutorials explaining `for` loops.
Thank's [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510294/mike) for mentioning the even spacing in the comments. Updated the code.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but has a small mistake. You should change System.out.print(x * y +  "    ") to System.out.print(x +  "    "), because yis undefined.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked for the most part. Nothing wrong on your part but its printing only 4 rows rather than the 5 that I input. Should I set x and y to 0 instead?

Comment: No, that would produce 0s in the output because of the multiplication. Replace the `<` (smaller) in the condition with `<=` (smaller or equals)

Comment: You will also need to change `System.out.print(y * x + "    ");` to `System.out.print(y * x + "\t");` if you wish to get the even spacing shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks mike, I was wondering about this too!

Answer (score 0):

When you do the

System.out.print(x * y +  "    ");

the second time, y = 5 as a result of the for loop.  Thus 2 *5 = 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 4 rows you want to show rows, 1,2,3, and 4. If you stop your loop at < 4 (rather than <= 4) you'll miss the last row, and column. This is what folks call a [fencepost error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) .

Try something like so:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= row; x++)
```

Also, the first print you don't yet have a good y value. You want both x and y to be valid, so only print inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x = 1; x < row; x++){
    System.out.print(x * y +  "    ");
    for(y = 1 ; y < column; y++){
        System.out.print(y * x + "    ");
    }
    System.out.println();   
}
```

The first print() is unneeded, and you need to change the comparison such that `row` and `column` are valid values for x and y respectively (i.e. used `<=` rather than `<`. Also, you will want to use `"\t"` (the tab character) to space out the columns, rather than `"     "`, so that numbers with a different number of digits do not cause the columns to skew. This should produce the expected results.

```
for(x = 1; x <= row; x++){
    for(y = 1 ; y <= column; y++){
        System.out.print(y * x + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();   
}
```

Output of 4,6 with `"    "`...

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    
2    4    6    8    10    12    
3    6    9    12    15    18    
4    8    12    16    20    24
```

Output of 4,6 with `"\t"`...

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   
2   4   6   8   10  12  
3   6   9   12  15  18  
4   8   12  16  20  24
```

Answer (score -2):

The first `print` is wrong, since it uses the `y` value from the previous for loop.

Change it to:

```
for(x = 1; x <= row; x++){
  System.out.print(x +  "    ");
  for(y = 1 ; y <= column; y++){
    System.out.print(y * x + "    ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Update: the loop end was also `<`, while they should be `<=` (since they're 1-based). I updated that in the fragment above.

Comment: I see, you are skipping the last row because of the `<`. I'll update the code above.